# Location permission error (access granted in info.plist)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS app that I have coded using Xamarin.
However, each time I get to a screen that requires access to location
I get an error message that states

> **The operation couldn't be completed.**  **(kCLErrorDomain error 0)**"

In the info.plist I have the following permission already given to the application

> **Location Always Usage Description** = "Would like to access your location"
>
> **Location When in Usage Description** = "Would like to access your location"

This error only shows up on one iPad but the other iPad doesn't seem to experience this error
In the iPad settings access is granted to the application, this was one of the checks I made to make sure that access was granted in the application

Answer (score 1):

> kCLErrorDomain **error 0**

That error code equals:

> kCLErrorLocationUnknown  = 0,  // location is currently unknown, but CL will keep trying

This is *usually* do to a CoreLocation manager failure due to not having access to GPS, Wifi and/or Cell network on the device. Does that iPad that is failing have Cellular, is it working, valid SIM, is Wifi on? Connected to a valid/working SSID, etc...

#### CLError.h:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CLError) {
    kCLErrorLocationUnknown  = 0,         // location is currently unknown, but CL will keep trying
    kCLErrorDenied,                       // Access to location or ranging has been denied by the user
    kCLErrorNetwork,                      // general, network-related error
    kCLErrorHeadingFailure,               // heading could not be determined
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied,       // Location region monitoring has been denied by the user
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure,      // A registered region cannot be monitored
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringSetupDelayed, // CL could not immediately initialize region monitoring
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringResponseDelayed, // While events for this fence will be delivered, delivery will not occur immediately
    kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult,         // A geocode request yielded no result
    kCLErrorGeocodeFoundPartialResult,    // A geocode request yielded a partial result
    kCLErrorGeocodeCanceled,              // A geocode request was cancelled
    kCLErrorDeferredFailed,               // Deferred mode failed
    kCLErrorDeferredNotUpdatingLocation,  // Deferred mode failed because location updates disabled or paused
    kCLErrorDeferredAccuracyTooLow,       // Deferred mode not supported for the requested accuracy
    kCLErrorDeferredDistanceFiltered,     // Deferred mode does not support distance filters
    kCLErrorDeferredCanceled,             // Deferred mode request canceled a previous request
    kCLErrorRangingUnavailable,           // Ranging cannot be performed
    kCLErrorRangingFailure,               // General ranging failure
};
```

Comment: the ipad has access to wifi